# Adding a value to a list box but separating them line by line as opposed to one line

Tags: javascript

How can the code be modified below so as to allow the newly added values to appear on separate lines as opposed to just on the same line when the add button is clicked?

Expected result:

```
Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
```

Current result:

```
RedBlueGreenYellow
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function add() {
  document.getElementById('list').value += " " + document.getElementById('input').value;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" style="width: 154px;" id="input">
<input onclick="add()" type="button" style="width: 20px; height: 22px;" value="+" id="add"><br>
<textarea style="height: 75px;" id="list"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the add function like,

```
function add() {
  document.getElementById('list').value += " " + document.getElementById('input').value;
}
```

Comment: Your code still adds it onto one line with a weird space in front of it.